# Daniel 12:11: one or two events? regular burnt offering is taken away AND the abomination that makes desolate is set up

Tags: daniel

> regular burnt offering is taken away AND the abomination that makes
> desolate is set up

In Greek, is there any indication whether this is meant to be read as:

- Two events, possibly separated by some time, like 'I changed my oil and went to sleep'
- One event like 'I changed my oil and cleaned up'

In our everyday speech 'I changed my oil and cleaned up' is assumed to be referring to the process of changing the oil and not of cleaning up something else like your house.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate the Hebrew thus (overly literally with slashes to show separate Hebrew words):

> From the time / is taken away / [the] continual / and is set up /
> [the] abomination / of desolation / days / thousand / two hundred /
> and ninety.

Other literal versions give a similar translation:

- YLT: and from the time of the turning aside of the perpetual sacrifice, and to the giving out of the desolating abomination, are days a thousand, two hundred, and ninety.
- NASB: And from the time that the regular sacrifice is abolished and the abomination of desolation is set up, there will be 1,290 days.
- ESV: And from the time that the regular burnt offering is taken away and the abomination that makes desolate is set up, there shall be 1,290 days.

There are definitely two events here:

- the taking away of the continual [= "daily sacrifice by some versions but this is interpretive]
- setting up of the abomination of desolation

These two events are joined by a common cumulative conjunction, "and" suggesting they are at the same time.  I cannot see any lexical and semantic reason to separate these events.

Now, whether one wishes to make these two events two names for the same occurrence, is another matter and one of interpretation and thus another question.

**APPENDIX 1 - LXX version of Dan 12:11**

The LXX reads:

> καὶ ἀπὸ καιροῦ παραλλάξεως τοῦ ἐνδελεχισμοῦ καὶ τοῦ δοθῆναι βδέλυγμα
> ἐρημώσεως ἡμέραι χίλιαι διακόσιαι ἐνενήκοντα.

L C L Brenton translates this (correctly as)

> And from the time of the removal of the perpetual sacrifice, when the
> abomination of desolation shall be set up, [there shall be] a thousand
> two hundred and ninety days.

Thus, the LXX places both events at the same time.

**APPENDIX 2 - Aramaic of Dan 12:11**

Aramaic in Plain English reads:

> And from the time that offering will pass away, the abomination of
> desolation shall be given for one thousand and two hundred and ninety
> days

Comment: Perfect!! + 1. It even becomes clearer that the 1290 days are in *continuance* of/from the 2 events, when one takes in Verse 12, where 45 days are added in further *continuance*.

Answer (score 0):

The text is originally Hebrew (with some parts in Aramaic), however there exists a Greek version in the Greek Old Testament too. If we're talking about the Hebrew/Aramaic Daniel (the original), it translates here to:

> From the **removal** of the daily sacrifice, unto the **substitution** with the abomination of desolation, there are a thousand two hundred and ninety days.

The operative words here are **"removed"** and **"given"** which in Hebrew and Aramaic have more technical uses sometimes (i.e. the meaning of the word "give" depends on context, and can mean *pay*, *reward*, *assign*, even *dedicate*, etc.); hence, I've translated it as "substitute" because of the immediate context. Either way, these words are opposites and so mark two points in time separated by the abovementioned period of time. Notice also that the period of time is described as "unto the," that is, "up to the [second point in time]," namely, up to the point when the abomination of desolation appears.

(I'll leave interpretation of the symbolic nature or lack thereof of the word "days" and the specific number of days up to the reader. Pre-Christian Jews believed that there was a — if not the — fulfillment of this verse during the persecution during the Maccabean revolt, when a true horror occurred — pagans placed an idol on the altar instead of the sacrifice and worshipped it, defiling the Temple, and they describe it according to the words of Daniel; cf. 1 Mac 1:57.)

For what it's worth, the Greek Old Testament has the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: May I question your first sentence? Is not the text we have of Daniel in Hebrew from Chapter 8 onwards to the end of the book?

Comment: Sorry for that, yes you're correct - I had originally intended to question/correct OP in that the text isn't Greek, and proceeded to keep talking about Aramaic and Hebrew even though it's Hebrew here. Thanks for catching.